# Eclipse stuck, 100% cpu

Tags: eclipse, crash

When I start Eclipse 3.8, it sticks at "Loading workbench", and gives the following errors in the log. I've searched and haven't found any solution to this... any ideas?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2012-09-29 18:48:14.449
!MESSAGE Ignored attempt to add saveable that was already registered
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: unknown saveable: org.eclipse.ui.internal.DefaultSaveable@1c3aee5b from part: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart@1c3aee5b
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.logWarning(SaveablesList.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.addModel(SaveablesList.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.addModels(SaveablesList.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.postOpen(SaveablesList.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.partOpened(PartList.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.access$0(PartList.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList$1.propertyChanged(PartList.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.fireInternalPropertyChange(WorkbenchPartReference.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-09-29 18:48:14.593
!MESSAGE Could not create view: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavadocView'.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-09-29 18:48:14.594
!MESSAGE Could not create view: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SourceView'.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-09-29 18:48:14.594
!MESSAGE Could not create view: 'org.eclipse.jdt.callhierarchy.view'.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-09-29 18:48:14.594
!MESSAGE Could not create view: 'com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.LogCatView'.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2012-09-29 18:48:15.088
!MESSAGE Perspective Java has been made into a local copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to a knwon eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=186977

As written here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349543#c4 ,

> This usually happens when one
>
> 1. opens editor(s)
> 2. exit Eclipse
> 3. start Eclipse
> 4. delete a project
> 5. click on an editor tab of a deleted file
>      ==> exceptions.

Some general pieces of advise whenever you get stuck with eclipse:

1. Start eclipse from command line with " -clean" option. this will force it to clean all eclipse cache (project and workspace caches)

   To do this, on Windows, run in a cmd shell "eclipse.exe -clean".

   On Mac, type this in a terminal "/path_to_eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean &"
2. If this doesn't work, rename your workspace folder to force eclipse to crate a new one: maybe it's related to some ugly stuff that happened within your workspace. Then, either try to reopen the previous workspace, or just import the project from 'buggy' workspace in the newly created one. However, you will loose your workspace specific settings, of course.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved the problem by stopping the indexer:

`Project properties-> C/C++ General->Indexer:check enable project specific settings, uncheck enable indexer`.